# Uma das minhas aplicações do shiny não está rodando em meu servidor

Tags: r, centos, shiny

Recentemente instalei o shiny em um servidor que tenho. Isto pode ser conferido clicando [neste link](http://177.20.146.204/). Eu gostaria de colocar neste servidor várias aplicações que já fiz e ainda pretendo fazer, como se fosse a [galeria do shiny no site do RStudio](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/).

Entretanto, não consigo fazer a minha primeira aplicação própria funcionar. Ela roda localmente no meu PC e no [shinyapps.io](https://marcusnunes.shinyapps.io/IMDb2/), mas ela não roda no meu servidor próprio. Não sou sysadmin, então meu conhecimento no manejo de servidores é bastante limitado.

Algo que percebi foi que as aplicações do shiny que aparecem no link de teste do servidor estão localizadas dentro da pasta `/srv/shiny-server/sample-apps`. Assim, posso acessá-las com os links http://177.20.146.204/sample-apps/hello e http://177.20.146.204/sample-apps/rmd.

Pensando nisso, copiei os arquivos `global.R`, `imdb.R`, `LICENSE`, `list.R`, `README.md`, `server.R` e `ui.R`, todos necessários para a minha aplicação, para a pasta `/srv/shiny-server/sample-apps/IMDb2`. Mas quando acesso o link http://177.20.146.204/sample-apps/IMDb2/, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> `An error has occurred`
>
> `The application failed to start.`
>
> `The application exited during initialization.`

Aparentemente, todas as permissões dos arquivos e das pastas estão corretas:

```
$ ls
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   32 Oct  6 13:40 hello
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4.0K Nov  7 09:56 IMDb2
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   22 Oct  6 13:40 rmd
```

Isto posto, minhas perguntas são

1. Como fazer esta minha aplicação específica rodar?
2. Como posso colocar minhas aplicações em um link mais amigável, como http://177.20.146.204/hello, sem o trecho sample-apps que é exigido coma configuração atual?

Comment: Remova o diretório `sample-apps`, ou seja, suba seus apps para `shiny-server`, assim resolve o problema do amigável.

Comment: Quanto às permissões, não acredito que tenha problemas, mas compare com os outros diretórios (apps).

Comment: Eu não tinha todos os pacotes necessários instalados no servidor. Era este o problema.

Comment: @MarcusNunes, que tal postar sua solução como resposta para usuários que enfrentes problemas similares no futuro? Não há muita documentação sobre o `shiny server` em português

Comment: O problema não era referente a nenhuma permissão nos arquivos ou na localização da minha pasta. Eu não havia instalado alguns dos pacotes necessários para a minha aplicação. Portanto, o shiny reportava `The application failed to start.`, mas não indicava que o problema era a falta de pacotes. Instalei-os e tudo ocorreu como deveria.

Comment: @TomásBarcellos boa ideia. Acabei de fazer isto.